# While inserting data into a table using a stored procedure and passing values as parameters, how can I add a check that data already exists

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, duplicates, subquery, sql-insert

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AddNewReview(
  RESTAURANTNAME IN VARCHAR2 (100)
, USERNAME IN VARCHAR2 (100)
, Stars IN Int
, RATINGDATE IN DATE 
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO newReview VALUES (RestaurantName, UserName, Stars, RatingDate);
END AddNewReview;
;
```

How can I add a check so that it inserts only when data is not present?

Comment: Use unique constraint on the logical key columns which will not allow you to insert the same data multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select ... where not exist (...)` to ensure that you are not duplicating data. Assuming that columns `RestaurantName`, `UserName` and `RatingDate` can be used as a (pseudo-)primary key:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AddNewReview(
    pRestaurantName IN VARCHAR2 (100),
    pUserName IN VARCHAR2(100),
    pStars IN INT,
    pRatingDate IN DATE 
) AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO newReview (RestaurantName, UserName, Stars, RatingDate)
    SELECT p.*
    FROM (
        SELECT pRestaurantName RestaurantName, 
            pUserName UserName, 
            pStars Stars, 
            pRatingDate RatingDate
        FROM DUAL
    ) p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM newReview r
        WHERE r.RestaurantName = p.RestaurantName 
          AND r.UserName = p.UserName 
          AND r.RatingDate = p.RatingDate
    )
END AddNewReview;
```

Note that I renamed the `IN` paramters so that they do not conflict with the column names. I also listed the target columns for insert. Both of these changes are good practices.